# Breakdown voltage dependence on permittivity/conductance

Tags: electrostatics, voltage

I'm trying to calculate the voltage breakdown of a material from its electrical conductivity or its conductivity. Is this possible? I've come across Paschen's Law, but this seems to apply only to gases and I'm interested in solid behaviour as well.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Nik

Comment: A breakdown voltage is a voltage at which you provide enough electrical energy to the material, that it starts a process which reduces its resistance. This can be because of reorganization of molecules, or can happen because the current that does flow sufficiently heats up the material, to a point where it becomes more conductive. 

It is not dependant on electrical conductivity of material itself. Different materials react differently.

Comment: In what situation would you have breakdown of a solid material? That's something I've never heard of happening before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate the breakdown voltage of a material from its electrical conductivity. Dielectric breakdown usually involves runaway processes due to the generation of additional charge carriers by high electric fields either by impact ionization or field ionization which at a critical voltage (or field) cause a sharp increase in conductance. There are also breakdown processes related to the effects of heating and possibly melting.